# Laravel relationship where clause is returning records outside relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a problem where i try to get all users from Site which is defined relationship in Site model and on where clause it returns users that belong to other Site

```
$searchArray = ['name'];
$searchParam; //from request
$query =  Site::findOrFail($site_id)->users();


foreach($searchArray as $key => $value){
     if ($key) {
         $query->orWhere($value, 'like', '%' . $searchParam . '%');
     } else {
         $query->where($value, 'like', '%' . $searchParam . '%');
     }
}
 $query->with('someTable');
 $query->orderBy($order);
 $query->paginate(10);
```

Lets say that my `$site_id = 2` and my `$searchParam = 'Tom'`. It returns Tom that belongs to Site with `site_id=1` but it also returns other Tom that belongs to Site with `site_id=2`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is because you use 'orWhere'. put the orWheres inside a `->where()` and this will be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation query works with a `->where()`, so your `->orWhere()` will give results outside the relation. You can fix this by using an extra `where()` like this:

```
$searchArray = ['name'];
$searchParam; //from request
$query =  Site::findOrFail($site_id)->users();

$query->where(function($q) use ($searchArray, $searchParam) {
  foreach($searchArray as $key => $value){
     if ($key) {
         $q->orWhere($value, 'like', '%' . $searchParam . '%');
     } else {
         $q->where($value, 'like', '%' . $searchParam . '%');
     }
  }
});
 $query->with('someTable');
 $query->orderBy($order);
 $query->paginate(10);
```